# sql server for json auto. How to get all of result

Tags: json, sql-server

When trying this:

```
select BtId, [Name], Type, ISNULL([Description], '') as [Description], 
ISNULL(Comment, '') as Comment, ISNULL(Source, '') as Source, ISNULL(Info, '') as Info

from BytegymType
For json auto
```

I get this error message:

```
Unable to show XML. The following error happened:
An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 14957.
One solution is to increase the number of characters retrieved from the 
server for XML data. To change this setting, on the Tools menu, click 
Options.
```

I have set the sql result to max:

[image: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17289.0]

The non-xml data i cant get over 655535 either..
I tried also result to file, still missing stuff.

Sorry I'm not too good with sql-server :(

Comment: "Line 1 position 14957"? Is the first line of your XML (JSON) really that wide? Really this sounds like you're trying to display a huge XML/JSON string within SSMS. If you really need to get out a value like that you shouldn't being using SSMS in the first place; it's not what it's really designed for. Use an ETL tool/process to create the appropriate the XML/JSON file in the file system.

Comment: The result is just one line in one colum, so yes. The table is not that big, 91 rows, 7 columns. Thought that was not too much...

Comment: @Larnu - when the JSON is first returned - for instance -  to the SSMS results pane, it is ALL one "line". Only after it is formatted and displayed in a new window does it appear as "multiple lines". "Lines" are often computers' way of prettifying bytestreams for human consumption.

Comment: Just want to add to this that you can also add null values like this:
For json auto, include_null_values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the error after going narrowing down the results. It had nothing to with the buffersize. The **for json** seems to have problems with the **&** sign, which i had stored in the db. It's kinda weird cause it did have release characters for /
The sentence was "Shoulders & Triceps".

Seems the parser is buggy.

Comment: Thank you! `replace(s.mach_descr,'&','')` absolutely solved my problem.

Comment: replace(column, '&', '&amp;') gives a better result, I think that since it is actually using the XML logic it expects the & to be a HTML entity.

The resulting json will have &amp; which will be need to replaced again to &

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, Azure Data Studio returns correct json result even if the data contains an ampersand (&).

Comment: Using Azure Data Studio works

Comment: Using Azure Data Studio does work to solve this ampersand problem, thank you.     NOTE: "Beginning with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.7, Azure Data Studio is automatically installed alongside SSMS."  -- so to use it just do a "search" on the startup menu (windows_key)